# How to create progress bar in javascript and how to use it at the time of page load of web page?

Tags: javascript

I want to show the progress bar in the web page when it is loading. How to create & use the progress bar in web site?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ready made jquery plugins
http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for jazzy look for your progress bars, try with these [stylings](http://www.red-team-design.com/stylish-css3-progress-bars)

Answer (score 0):

Create an overlay with z-index higher than the rest of the site, give that opacity of 75%, on top of that create a box that has z-index one higher than your overlay. When your dom is done loading, hide the overlay box and the box above it.

Thats the simplified version of creating a loading box, only using javascript when wanting to hide it.

Comment: can u show me the demo example because i'm new learner of the web application?

Answer (score 0):

There are Frameworks to do this. For example you could use Dojo. (http://dojotoolkit.org/)
With this framework you could define a Progressbar directly in your html code.

```
<div dojoType="dijit.ProgressBar" style="width:300px"
id="downloadProgress" maximum="10">
```

For details see http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/ProgressBar.html

You could also easily update your progressbar while your page loads:

```
dijit.byId("downloadProgress").update({
            maximum: 10,
            progress: i++
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML-5 Canvas element to create an animated Progress Bar.

Something like

```
ctx.fillRect(10,10,x,50);
```

and then set an FPS-controlled interval which increments `x`.

This [tutorial](http://www.splashnology.com/article/how-to-create-a-progress-bar-with-html5-canvas/478/) may come in handy.

You can later trigger it's animation on page load, using the DOM.